How to inform typescript an optional parameter is present in Array.map
I have a list of objects defined by
type Foo = {
    x?: string[]
    y: number
}

Now I would like to filter this list based on the presence of x
const list: Foo[] = [
    { y: 2},
    { x: ['a'], y: 9}
] 

list
    .filter(item => item.x !== undefined)
    .map(item => item.x[0] || '-')

Example
However, there is an error in the last line telling me that x might be undefined. It makes sense as x is options, but I know, in this case, it is defined.
I can only think of solution which is quite long using a guard
...

interface Test extends Foo {
    x:  string[]
}

function isWithX(inp: Foo): inp is Test {
    return !!inp.x
}

list
    .filter(item => isWithX(item) )
    .map(item => item.x.length > 0 ? item.x[0] : '-' )

Example
It involves an extra interface and a function, just to let typescript know it is save to use x. Is there a shorter way to solve this error (without suppressing it)?

No reason to make it a separate function? .filter(isWithX) or .filter((inp: Foo): inp is Test => …) both work. You can even write the Test type inline if you want to avoid the interface declaration.

ok, that is indeed better. But good to know that this is the way to do it! Thnx

This is yet another instance of the lack of ms/TS#42384. If that were implemented your code would probably work without modification. You could manually implement a general version of ms/TS#42384 as shown in this playground link, but if you're only doing this once you might as well make the type guard function similar to how you're doing it (it can be put inline but you still have to manually annotate the type predicate). Does @Bergi want to write an answer or find a duplicate here?

@jcalz nah thanks I'm fine :P

Is there a  way to do this without using an Interface, maybe something with Omit<..> and adding the required x field?

^ Who are you asking? You can write guardObjByProp and do it generically or you can write your Test type however you want. You could write Required<Foo> or Foo & {x: string[]} or Omit<Foo, "x"> & {x: string[]} etc.
